# Sonar remote access

Tags: sonarqube

I've installed Sonarqube 4.1.1 on a windows 64 bit system. I have no problems connecting to the web client on the same machine where I installed it. But I have no remote access - even in the same network (so I don't need ip forwarding and so on).

As I thought the port might be the problem, I switched my other tomcat installation to this port and it worked remotely. Only if I try to access sonar remotely it doesn't work.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=8082

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# Access logs are generated in the file logs/access.log. This file is rolled over when it's 5Mb.
# An archive of 3 files is kept in the same directory.
# Access logs are enabled by default.
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true
```

This is my sonar.properties file (the relevant part).

Comment: Your properties file is fine, so none of that info is really relavent.. running `http://servername:8082` should work. what errors are you receiving?

Comment: There is no error. The browser just says that no connection can be established to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be late on this post. I am using Sonarqube Community Edition 8.8 and I was facing same issue, was able to access on localhost and not using IP. In sonar.properties I changed sonar.web.host from 0.0.0.0 to sonar.web.host = "*" and restarted sonarqube. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should change sonar.web.host from 0.0.0.0 to your server ip in sonar.properties file. Then restart sonarqube.

Comment: Sonar is not starting for me after changing this property. Any clue why?